# Bind DataGrid in WPF to child navigation property (EF) with 1:1 using MVVM

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wpfdatagrid, one-to-one

Bind DataGrid in WPF to child navigation property (EF) with 1:1 using MVVM

All,

Using .Net 4 and EF 4.4 (DB first)

I have a ViewModel that contains a reference to an EntityCollection "Entity1".

This Entity has a 1:1 relationship with Entity2.

My problem is that, while I can bind to other Entities that have a 1:many or many:many relationship, I seem to have trouble binding to Entity1.Entity2.  My guess is this is because Entity2 is not a collection, and so WPF isn't quite sure what to do with this.

So, outside of adding an ObservableCollection to my Entity1 class (which will only contain 1 instance of Entity2, being a 1:1 relationship) and binding to this, I was wondering if there was perhaps a better way to accomplish my goal of having Entity1.Entity2 display in a DataGrid (without redesigning my DB or creating an unnecessary collection that will ultimately only contain 1 object).

I've already tried putting Entity1.Entity2 inside of a CollectionViewSource, but that doesn't seem to help any.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a datagrid for a single entity? I definitely would not stick an ObservableCollection property in your model to cover this.

If you are wanting to show all entity2s for all entity1s. You can bind the ItemsSource of your datagrid to a collection of entity1 and drill in to the properties of entity2.

Another option is to build a custom form for presenting the entity2 data.

**Attempt 1**

<strike>You can definitely drill into the properties in Entity2 from Entity1. 
Try this:</strike>

1. Populate an ObservableCollection with the instances of Entity1
   that you want to use.
2. Set the ItemsSource on your DataGrid to
   that ObservableCollection
3. Set AutoGenerateColumns to false on
   your DataGrid
4. Add the columns you desire to the datagrid setting the binding path to be Entity2.PropertyName
5. You may have to temporarily create an instance of Entity2 for each Entity1 for this to work.

**Attempt 2**
Entity Framework will allow for a single entity to be constructed from two tables. You may want to consider that implementation. The big question there is "do I really care if I have worthless records in Table2 if Table2 only extends Table1?"

**Attempt 3**
Instead of working with Entity1 and Entity2 directly, I think you should introduce a new model into your domain. Having a class that would wrap the properties of Entity1 and Entity2 is probably going to be the best choice. Then, when you are ready to update the database, you can determine if you have an instance of Entity2.

Following the WPF Application Framework, you might have something like this:

```
//In your application layer

public class RecordsViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Record> Records {get;set;}
}


//In your domain layer

public class Record
{
    //Properties from Entity1

    //Properties from Entity2
}

//In your Data Access Layer

public class Repository
{
    public IEnumerable<Record> GetRecords()
    {
        return db.Entity1.Include("Entity2")
                .Select(e => 
                    new Record() 
                        { 
                            //object initialization
                        });
    }

    public void Update(IEnumerable<Record> records)
    {
        var recordIds = records.Select(r => r.Id);

        var entities = db.Entity1.Include("Entity2").Where(e => recordIds.Contains(e.Id));

        foreach(var record in records)
        {
            var entity = entities.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == record.Id);

            if (entity == null)
            {
                entity = new Entity1();
                db.Entity1.Add(entity);
            }

            //update properties on Entity1

            //check if Entity2 should exist
            //If so, create/update entity2
            //If not, decide if you should delete entity2 or simply set Entity1.Entity2 to null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have reasons for using DataGrid for a single entity.  Now, my question is, if I reference Entity1 in ItemsSource, and use Entity2.Property for each column in ItemsSource, will this have any implications for when Entity1.Entity2 is null?  It would seem to me I'd have to check for Entity1.Entity2 != null, then assign Entity2 before I could edit, but the problem is that I want Entity1.Entity2 to be null most of the time and it would seem easier (although a bit of a nasty hack) to modify the T4 template (which I've already done) and have an ObservableCollection<Entity2> kept in sync with Entity2

Comment: I am.  I'd like to be able to allow end-user to add a row without clicking any button (DataGrid.AllowUserToAddRows=True) if at all possible.  I have an IValueConverter in place, however, that prevents the end-user from being able to add too many rows.  All the more reason I'm leaning toward just putting my object inside of a collection and binding to that.

Comment: So, the user is working with multiple Entity1s that may or may not have an Entity2?

Comment: Correct.  Entity1:Entity2 is a 1:0 or 1:1 relationship.

Comment: Isn't that what my ViewModel that contains a reference to Entity1 (and Entity1.Entity2) is doing?  Seems like the main difference between your suggestion and my suggestion is that you're suggesting I move the ObservableCollection<Entity2> that I created inside of my Entity1 class (which has scope of only the Entity1 instance) to outside of Entity1 class (and into my ViewModel (?) which has scope of all Entities in collection that I'd then have to drill down to).  Perhaps I'm missing something (I'm sure I am), but I fail to see how this is any less complicated.

Comment: I've added a bit of code to Attempt 3 to illustrate what I mean. I've also changed Attempt 2.

Comment: Okay.  I see what you're getting at.  I like it, but it seems like more work then simply doing the following (see answer):

Comment: @user1721649, I used to think that same way. You'll be surprised how fast that code gets written. Also, I think it falls more in line with Domain-Driven Design. If you do decide it is worth the effort, I believe you will feel it was worth it in the end.

Comment: Okay.  I'll give your way a go, then, and see what I come up with.  Will let you know if I run into any issues.

Comment: I had issue with your way because of the inherent disconnect between DAL and the ObservableCollection<customtype>.  Seems like more noise, not less.  I reverted to my original plan and seemed to have solved my issue.  One added benefit to this is that if I update my model, I won't have to go back and change the properties in my custom class.

Answer (score 0):

ATTEMPT 1:
In T4 Template that creates Entity classes, change NavigationProperty to:

```
public string NavigationProperty(NavigationProperty navigationProperty)
{
    var endType = _typeMapper.GetTypeName(navigationProperty.ToEndMember.GetEntityType());

    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "{0}\n\n    {1}  {2}  {3}\n    {{\n      {4}get\n        {{\n           return _{3}; \n        }}\n        {5} set\n        {{\n          _{3}=value; OnSet{3}();\n        }}\n      }}\n\n    {6}",
        string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} _{1};",_typeMapper.GetTypeName(navigationProperty.TypeUsage), _code.Escape(navigationProperty)),
        AccessibilityAndVirtual(Accessibility.ForProperty(navigationProperty)),
        navigationProperty.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many ? ("ICollection<" + endType + ">") : endType,
        _code.Escape(navigationProperty),
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(navigationProperty)),
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(navigationProperty)),
        string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "partial void OnSet{0}();", _code.Escape(navigationProperty)));
}
```

Then add in partial Entity1 Class:

```
Partial Class Entity1:EntityBase
{
    public SpecificObservableCollection<Entity2> Entity2_Observable
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    partial void OnSetEntity2()
    {
        Misc_Observable.Add(Entity2);
    }
    public class SpecificObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
    {
        public Action<T> SetValue { get; set; }
        protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                base.InsertItem(index, item);
            }
        }
        protected override void OnCollectionChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
            if (this.Count>0)
                SetValue(this[0]);
        }
    }

    protected override void DoStuffOnAdd()
    {
            Entity2_Observable = new SpecificObservableCollection<Entity2>();
            Entity2_Observable.SetValue = a => _Entity2 = a;
    }
}
```

Then in EntityBase:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    EntityBase()
    {
        DoStuffOnAdd();
    }
    protected virtual void DoStuffOnAdd() { }
}
```

For IValueConverter (in order to avoid adding too many records in a 1:1 relationship)

```
public class CanAddValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
   private Type _T;
   private DataGrid _dg;

   public void SetValues(DataGrid dg, Type T)
   {
       _T = T;
       _dg = dg;
   }

   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
       System.Collections.IEnumerable dgIS = value as System.Collections.IEnumerable;
       if (_dg != null && dgIS == _dg.ItemsSource)
       {
           if (_dg.Items.Count > 0)
               return _dg.Items.Count <= System.Convert.ToInt32(parameter) && _dg.Items[_dg.Items.Count - 1].GetType() != _T;
           else
               return true;
       }
       else
           return false;
   }
}
```

then in CodeBehind, assign DataGrid to IValueConverter as well as corresponding Entity type.